# Replace synchronized with atomic+while loop in case of low lock contention

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have two functions which must run in a critical section:

```
public synchronized void f1() { ... }
public synchronized void f2() { ... }
```

Assume that the behavior is as following:

- `f1` is almost never called. Actually, under normal conditions, this method is never called. If `f1` is called anyway, it should return quickly.
- `f2` is called at a very high rate. It returns very quickly.
- These methods never call each other and there is no reentrancy as well.

In other words, there is very low contention. So when `f2` is called, we have some overhead to acquire the lock, which is granted immediately in 99,9% of the cases. I am wondering if there are approaches to avoid this overhead.

I came up with the following alternative:

```
private final AtomicInteger lock = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void f1() {
    while (!lock.compareAndSet(0, 1)) {}

    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.set(0);
    }
}

public void f2() {
    while (!lock.compareAndSet(0, 2)) {}

    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.set(0);
    }
}
```

Are there other approaches? Does the `java.util.concurrent` package offer something natively?

**update**

Although my intention is to have a generic question, some information regarding my situation:

`f1`: This method creates a new remote stream, if for some reason the current one becomes corrupt, for example due to a timeout. A remote stream could be considered as a socket connection which consumes a remote queue starting from a given location:

```
private Stream stream;

public synchronized void f1() {
     final Stream stream = new Stream(...);

     if (this.stream != null) {
         stream.setPosition(this.stream.getPosition());
     }
     this.stream = stream;
     return stream;
}
```

`f2`: This method advances the stream position. It is a plain setter:

```
public synchronized void f2(Long p) {
    stream.setPosition(p);
}
```

Here, `stream.setPosition(Long)` is implemented as a plain setter as well:

```
public class Stream {
    private volatile Long position = 0;

    public void setPosition(Long position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

In `Stream`, the current position will be sent to the server periodically asynchronously. Note that `Stream` is not implemented by myself.

My idea was to introduce compare-and-swap as illustrated above, and mark `stream` as `volatile`.

Comment: Why are they synchronized? What resource is being accessed concurrently? This is what you should focus on

Comment: @JeanLogeart I follow your thought process, but I would like to omit that from the question. That is, consider this is a generic/educational question.

Comment: Those `while` loops become busy loops until the lock value is updated.  Does profiling show a bottleneck?

Comment: @AndrewS In this specific scenario, the `while` loop in `f2` is almost always an `if`. Again, this is a generic question.

Comment: If you want mutual exclusion, `synchonized` is a better and more natural choice. You better block the thread and not consume any CPU than burning CPU cycles to check if you are not blocked any more. Those cycles can be used for computation for some other thread.

Comment: @JeanLogeart just running a simple test I see that `synchronized` is about 50% slower than the atomic int version

Comment: @flakes That is true in simple scenarios, but keep in mind that is at the expense of CPU. If you were trying to execute work on the side (for instance responding to queries in a server, other programs, etc), the `while` loop will cost you.

Comment: Have you considered using `ReentrantReadWriteLock`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Comment: How are you benchmarking, and with which JVM?  In a simple jmh benchmark, the CAS solution is faster for me when running under JDK 8, but `synchronized` dominates under JDK 11.  I advise using `synchronized` over busy CAS spinning when contention is low.  Performance is usually about the same, and it's easier to reason about.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Interesting, thanks. I did not yet do any benchmarking, I am currently mostly interested in different approaches. That said, I am currently targeting OpenJDK v8.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I made a simple timer `System.nanoTime` to calculate time for a billion iterations of a method which uses `synchronized` /`AtomicInt` and where the critical section is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description and your example code, I've inferred the following:

1. `Stream` has its own internal position, and you're also tracking the most recent `position` externally.  You use this as a sort of 'resume point': when you need to reinitialize the stream, you advance it to this point.
2. The last known `position` may be stale; I'm assuming this based on your assertion that the stream periodically does *asynchronously* notifies the server of its current position.
3. At the time `f1` is called, the stream is known to be in a bad state.
4. The functions `f1` and `f2` access the same data, and may run concurrently.  However, neither `f1` nor `f2` will **ever run concurrently against itself**.  In other words, you *almost* have a single-threaded program, except for the rare cases when both `f1` and `f2` are executing.

   *[**Side note:** My solution doesn't actually care if `f1` gets called concurrently with itself; it only cares that `f2` is not called concurrently with itself]*

If any of this is wrong, then the solution below is wrong.  Heck, it might be wrong anyway, either because of some detail left out, or because I made a mistake.  Writing **low-lock code is hard**, which is exactly why you should avoid it unless you've **observed an actual performance issue**.

```
static class Stream {
    private long position = 0L;

    void setPosition(long position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}

final static class StreamInfo {
    final Stream stream = new Stream();
    volatile long resumePosition = -1;

    final void setPosition(final long position) {
        stream.setPosition(position);
        resumePosition = position;
    }
}

private final Object updateLock = new Object();
private final AtomicReference<StreamInfo> currentInfo = new AtomicReference<>(new StreamInfo());

void f1() {
    synchronized (updateLock) {
        final StreamInfo oldInfo = currentInfo.getAndSet(null);
        final StreamInfo newInfo = new StreamInfo();

        if (oldInfo != null && oldInfo.resumePosition > 0L) {
            newInfo.setPosition(oldInfo.resumePosition);
        }

        // Only `f2` can modify `currentInfo`, so update it last.
        currentInfo.set(newInfo);

        // The `f2` thread might be waiting for us, so wake them up.
        updateLock.notifyAll();
    }
}

void f2(final long newPosition) {
    while (true) {
        final StreamInfo s = acquireStream();

        s.setPosition(newPosition);
        s.resumePosition = newPosition;

        // Make sure the stream wasn't replaced while we worked.
        // If it was, run again with the new stream.
        if (acquireStream() == s) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private StreamInfo acquireStream() {
    // Optimistic concurrency: hope we get a stream that's ready to go.
    // If we fail, branch off into a slower code path that waits for it.
    final StreamInfo s = currentInfo.get();
    return s != null ? s : acquireStreamSlow();
}

private StreamInfo acquireStreamSlow() {
    synchronized (updateLock) {
        while (true) {
            final StreamInfo s = currentInfo.get();

            if (s != null) {
                return s;
            }

            try {
                updateLock.wait();
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the stream has faulted and is being replaced by `f1`, it is possible that an earlier call to `f2` is still performing some operations on the (now defunct) stream.  I'm assuming this is okay, and that it won't introduce undesirable side effects (beyond those already present in your lock-based version).  I make this assumption because we've already established in the list above that your resume point may be stale, and we also established that `f1` is only called once the stream is known to be in a bad state.

Based on my JMH benchmarks, this approach is around 3x faster than the CAS or synchronized versions (which are pretty close themselves).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, very much appreciated. The idea of having a 'fast' and a 'slow' path to acquire the stream is an interesting one. Though, I am not sure if the code above is correct. Let me explain. Assume thread `t1` is executing `f1` and is about to execute `currentInfo = newInfo;`. Now, thread `t2` executes `f2(position)`. Assume that `acquireStream()` can just quickly return the current stream. Now the calls `s.setPosition(newPosition);` and `s.resumePosition = newPosition;` will be lost forever, because `t1` is not seeing that anymore in `f1`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You’re correct, and the code assumes that `f1` is only called once the stream is known to have faulted, so any concurrent work done by `f2` is “lost” (in the sense that it would be unable to complete since the “old” stream is broken).

Comment: Right, I did take that inferred assumption into account. Though I am not sure if I understand your assumption and if it is practical. Typically, `f1` is only called when the stream/socket is broken, for example due to a disconnect. Unless you have a way to 'pause' other threads (which might call `f2`), you always have a critical section between `f1` and `f2`? So I am not really sure what you mean with "the code assumes that `f1` is only called once the stream is known to have faulted".

Comment: What I mean is, if `f1` is only called when the stream is in a bad state, then what does it matter if `f2` runs concurrently with the old stream?  When `f2` tries to modify or consume the (bad) stream, wouldn't it just fail?  If this is a flawed assumption, then as you say, my solution is broken.

Comment: The main concern is that the position is inherited from the old stream. As you could see in the code snippet, `Stream.setPosition(pos)` is actually a simple setter. Is does not do any network IO. So whenever a new stream is created, I want to make sure that it always inherits the position from the old (bad) stream. That's why I believe there is a critical section between `f1` and `f2` which cannot be avoided.

Comment: @pbillen If that's what you're worried about, and if `f2` is really that simple (it only advances the stream), then all you really need to do is replace the 'get' operation in `f1` with an atomic get-and-set, and verify that the stream hasn't changed before exiting `f2` (and if it *did* change, then retry the operation).  I updated my answer to show you what I mean.  Even this should still be ~2x as fast as the CAS-based version.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated. That's an interesting approach. Basically `f2` keeps repeating until we know for sure that the stream hasn't been updated during its execution. Under normal conditions, it just has to execute once. I did not really think about using `AtomicReference` in such approach. I'm going to experiment tomorrow and accept your answer, as this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: I'm curious why this is 2x faster than the initial CAS version with `AmoticInteger`. Is this mainly because now we do twice a `get` (`currentInfo.get()` in `acquireStream()`, while originally, I was doing a conditional `compareAndset` and a plain `set`? I can see that this is slower, but I am wondering if there other reasons.

Comment: @pbillen An interlocked compare-exchange instruction will usually be more expensive than a read with volatile semantics (or even a handful of such reads).  If you can avoid the CAS on the common code path, so much the better.  Doing a CAS when you only need to do a read will also thrash your CPU's cache unnecessarily.

Comment: Interesting. Many thanks, I wish I could upvote you twice ;).

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't doing what you want it to. You are actually executing your code when the lock **is** being used. Try something like this:

```
public void f1() {
    while (!lock.compareAndSet(0, 1)) {
    }

    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.set(0);
    }
}
```

To answer your question, I don't believe that this will be any faster than using `synchronized` methods, and this method is harder to read and comprehend.

Comment: Oops, thank you. I altered my question to reflect this.

Comment: @pbillen Ah okay, got it. Have you run a test with the updated version? I wouldn't expect it to be much faster (if any) than a simple `synchronized` method.

Comment: "I don't believe that this will be any faster than using synchronized methods" Not true. Using synchronized is about 50% slower than the atomic int version, at least on my machine

Comment: As a percentage, this is much faster, but if the locked section is non trivial you won't notice the difference. If it is trivial you might be better off making the operation atomic instead of wrapping like this.

Comment: @JeffBrower I believe it depends on the rate of which the method is called and the computational complexity. As stated, `f2` is called at a very high rate and it returns very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a timestamp lock which works like a modification count. This works well if you have a high read to write ratio.

Another approach is to have an immutable object which stores state via an AtomicReference. This works well if you have a very high read to write ratio.

Comment: @pbillen It would be useful to know the behavioral differences between `f1` and `f2`.  For example, if only one of them performs modifications, then that is useful information, because that's something we can optimize for.